# How to prove that an everywhere differentiable function on [a,b] whose derivative is Lebesgue integrable is absolutely continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

This is a problem in chapter 3 of stein's real analysis. There is a hint saying an everywhere differentiable function whose derivative is non-negative almost everywhere is increasing, and hence an almost everywhere zero derivative implies the function be a constant. But I don't know how to use this fact to prove the original problem.

Comment: Welcome. This is usually presented as a theorem, rather than an exercise. Read through the theory, starting page 119, of [this](https://s2pnd-matematika.fkip.unpatti.ac.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Real-Analysis-4th-Ed-Royden.pdf) text

Comment: Can you tell us what the original problem was?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/

Comment: @FShrike That part of theory often uses the uniform integrability of divided difference of f. But in my problem how could I prove the uniform integrability from everywhere differentiability? Or there are other approaches? Can you explain more explicitly?

Comment: I can’t explain more explicitly unless you give a more explicit problem. That text I sent you has *everything* you need for this problem; just read it! If you have trouble with a specific bit of the content of the text, now you can edit your post to have a **precise** question and you can get help with that